# Google Play Importing downloader library

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

When I try to import Google Play Downloader Library to use I get an error in this line of code:

```
import com.android.vending.expansion.downloader.R;
```

It says that this import cannot be resolved

Btw, at first when I imported the library I got a lot more errors I had to correct by removing res folder which was duplicated inside the original res folder, and renaming the packages from

```
src.com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader
```

to

```
com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader
```

I tried

```
import com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.R
```

but I still get the same error

Comment: try with `Ctrl + shift + o` and then try again after `cleaning` the project.

Comment: It replaces the imported line with `import android.R` which I don't think this is right since it gives later in the code more errors in lines like `R.string.state_idle` that state_idle (or other strings) is not a field

Comment: then your `.jar` file is not added in `Java build path`. chack is it added or not. `Project properties => Java Build Path => Order and Export`

Comment: What .jar file? I have only `android.jar` under Android 4.1.2 and `licensing_library.jar` under Android Dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It seems I shouldn't have deleted the second res folder inside the original res folder... I should copy the files in the second res folder into the original res folder and then delete the (now empty) second res folder...

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by first and second res folder? I'm having the same issue, trying to get Android to run using expansion files